# How do i get with GetFiles only images and text files?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

This will get all the files:

```
static void DirSearch(string sDir)
{
    try
    {
        foreach (string d in Directory.GetDirectories(sDir))
        {
            foreach (string f in Directory.GetFiles(d))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(f);
            }
            DirSearch(d);
        }
    }
    catch (System.Exception excpt)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(excpt.Message);
    }
}
```

But I want to get all or most of images types files and text files only.

Comment: have you looked at all the `GetFiles()` Overloads ..? come on now.. do a simple google search ...! this can be done with Linq.. also what `ext` are the image files...`..Jpg.Gif`....???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is something you can do you need to understand `Linq && Lambda Extension Methods \ Expressions`

```
var fi = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(sDir).GetFiles().
     Where(f => !(f.FullName.EndsWith(".jpg") || f.Name.EndsWith(".txt"))).ToArray();
```

Comment: It's good that you answer his question. But you're also pointing out that this is an easy google search. Seems a bit sharp on both edges.

Answer (score 1):

try class ***Path()*** and it's functions like ***GetExtension()***

Answer (score 1):

One way is to created a list of file extensions you are interested in then add those files that match to a list.

```
List<string> validextentions = new List<string> {"bmp", "jpg", "gif"};
DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\MyFolder\MyImages\");

List<FileInfo> myFiles = (from file in d.GetFiles("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                where validextentions.Contains(file.Extension.Replace(".", "").ToLower())
                select new FileInfo(file.FullName)).ToList();
```